# How to INSERT data in Nested Table from Nested Table BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 Nested Tables and I want to INSERT INTO each other.

I try this :

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( record.id, record.product.type, record.product.price )
SELECT
 id
 product.type
 product.price
FROM table 2
```

or this :

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( record.id, record.product )
VALUES (
      STRUCT((select id from table2)),
      STRUCT((select product.type from table2))
  )
```

BQ alert :

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "." at [1:62] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions.
```

But don't works ..

table 1

```
record                      RECORD  NULLABLE    
record.id                   STRING  NULLABLE    
record.product              RECORD  NULLABLE    
record.product.type         STRING  NULLABLE    
record.product.price        FLOAT   NULLABLE
```

table 2

```
id                      STRING  NULLABLE    
product                 RECORD  NULLABLE    
product.type            STRING  NULLABLE    
product.price           FLOAT   NULLABLE
```

How can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT STRUCT(id, STRUCT(productPrice.type, productPrice.price)) FROM table2;
```

Comment: Please consider voting up and accepting this answer if it helped !

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **APPLY** operator to unpivot a table
please visit this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27708046/1862306